# Automatically log out users when tab is closed using asp.net forms authentication

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, forms

I have a simple web form that uses forms authentication. To implement the authentication, I have this in the web.config

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms loginUrl="Logon.aspx" name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH"></forms>
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
        <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization> 
  </system.web>
```

and in the codebehind on logon.aspx I use this to let them into the form if their credentials work:

```
FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(FormID, false);
```

FormID is just an identifier either generated on the logon page for a new form, or entered by the user to continue an existing form. When they complete the form or click the button to start a new form I use this to send them back to the logon page:

```
FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
```

The issue I'm worried about is that users might lose track of which FormID they're currently working on, and fill out information for the wrong ID (it is displayed on the form for them, but they might ignore it). So I want to automatically sign them out whenever they refresh the page, close the tab, or close the browser (thus forcing them to explicitly enter the ID to continue the form). With the current code, it does sign them out when they close the browser, but not when they close the tab or refresh the page.

Is there a way for me to detect the tab closing or refresh and sign them out? Either code behind or javascript?

Comment: Why would you sign them out to accomplish this? And wouldn't refreshing the page and getting logged out or changing forms be a confusing user experience?

Comment: keeping them logged in but going to a different form doesn't make anything easier, but does increase risk that someone will accidentally enter a form with wrong identity (ie multiple users on shared devices). So I still want to require them to confirm the FormID if they close tab etc. 

If it helps think of the combined pair {user, FormID} as the base identity we're working with.

Comment: I'm confused. Why do you force them to log out after they submit a form? Like @mason said, this will make it confusing and not user-friendly. If I had to log in every time I wanted to fill out a new form on the site, I would rage. The user's identity does not need to change if they logged in successfully. If your forms need a unique identifier then add one based off of their currently logged in credentials, the date-time, and/or some RNG. Don't force them to re-log every time. Just generate a new form ID for each new submission.

Comment: It does log them out on submit. That's easy. I think people are focusing too much on the logging in or not. The information needed to generate a new form is identical to the information needed to log in, and also identical to the information needed to resume an existing form, so staying logged in is no benefit here, just a complication.